# Why is CakePHP 2.3.0 adding a '1' to my Form Post Values?

Tags: forms, cakephp, post

I'm using cakephp 2.3.0. I searched in the manual for quite awhile, but I haven't found the answer. Also, I've searched the Internet, but still haven't found what I'm looking for. SO, I'm posting my question here. Note, I'm fairly new to cakephp.

Scenario:

- I have a simple form with two fields: activity and zip code.
- I'm using POST on the form.
- When I type in some value in those fields and submit, I echo those 'post' values/parameters and display in the browser screen. What I typed in, I can see on the screen, but the number '1' is added to the end of what I typed in the form.
- Here is an example. I type in these values in the form, 'walk' and '44555'. Then I click 'Submit'. The post goes to my controller's action, which then calls my view. My view is displayed on the browser screen and I echo out those 'post' values. The results on screen are 'walk1' and '445551'.
- Example #2: If I follow the steps above and don't enter any values in my form (I'll add error checking later), what I see on the browser screen is '1' and '1'.

I am unable to figure out why I am getting the value of '1' added to my form's POST values?
I'll be glad to include any other additional php code to this posting, if requested by someone trying to help.

Here is my FORM code (from my view)...I know there are DIV helpers, but I'll get to that later:

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, array('url' => array('controller'=>'activities', 'action'=>'results'))); ?>
        <div class="box1" style="position:relative; top:10px; left:10px; float: left;"> 
            Search here.... <br>
            <hr>

                <?php echo $this->Form->input('activityName', array('size'=>'30', 
                                            'label'=>'Activity Name:', 'value'=>'i.e. walking, etc.'));?>
                <br>            
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('zip', array('size'=>'7', 'label'=>'Postal Code:')); ?>
            <br>
        </div>
    <div class="box1" align="right"> 
                <?php echo $this->Form->end('Go Search');?>
        </div>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
<?php

    class ActivitiesController extends AppController {

        public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

        public function index() {
            //other code....            
        }

        public function results() {
            $this->layout = 'second';    
            $name = $this->request->data['Activity']['activityName'];
            $pCode = $this->request->data['Activity']['zip'];
            $this->set('theName', $name);
            $this->set('theZip', $pCode);
            $this->set('results', $this->Activity->
                    find('all', array('conditions' => array('name' => $name, 'postal_code' => $pCode)))); 

            $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Results');
            $this->render();
        }
    }       
?>
```

My final view code. I left off some of the code...just showing the part that matters:

```
<div style="position:relative; top:10px; left:5px; "> 
    <?php echo print_r($theName); ?>
        <br>
    <?php echo print_r($theZip); ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: you add it somewhere. it can also be some boolean value you attach by accident. you really need to show more code here.

Comment: This code by itself should not append the value with an additional "1", show us your Controller/View code as well.

Comment: I added more detail. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The `1` comes from printing the return value of `print_r()` which is `true` (i.e. `1`).

In other words: you shouldn't do `echo print_r()`, just do `print_r()`. The function handles the printing by itself, you don't have to print the results manually.

(Also, `print_r()` is almost never the best choice to print out values except when debugging and even then CakePHP's `debug()` is much more suitable.)

Comment: Got it, thanks! Looks like I should have used debug()....still learning my way around cakephp. :)  Thanks for the speedy responses.